# Right align columns in Shiny dataTable

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have a Shiny data table that I am trying to right align. The data table has 2 columns.

I am using the following options:

```
  ,options= list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE, sorting = FALSE,  bFilter = FALSE, bSort = FALSE, bInfo = FALSE, bAutoWidth = TRUE, 
                 aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignRight",aTargets=c(list(1), list(2))))
```

What am I missing

Comment: You may try the DT package, which aligns numeric columns to the right by default: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `rowCallback` function to your list of options to align the text to the right using CSS (there doesn't seem to be any `rightAlign` or `dt-right` class styles in the CSS stylesheets loaded by shiny):

```
rowCallback = I(
    'function(row, data) {
        $("td", row).css("text-align", "right");
      }'
  )
```